# How to focus active menu item in sidebar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my sidebar code

```
<div><ul class="menusubnav">
<li class="orange"><a href="Managerhomepage.php">Manager</a></li>
<li><a href="addcustomerpage.php">New Customer</a></li>
<li><a href="EditCustomer.php">Edit Customer</a></li>
<li><a href="DeleteCustomerInput.php">Delete Customer</a></li>
<li><a href="addAccount.php">New Account</a></li>
<li><a href="editAccount.php">Edit Account</a></li>
<li><a href="deleteAccountInput.php">Delete Account</a></li>
<li><a href="MiniStatementInput.php">Mini Statement</a></li>
<li><a href="CustomisedStatementInput.php">Customised Statement</a></li>
<li><a href="Logout.php">Log out</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

and here is my css code

```
.menusubnav li{
    margin-top:0px; padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.menusubnav a{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin:0px; padding:10px; display:block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    font: 12px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none; color: #333;
}
.menusubnav a:hover{
    background-color:#FEF5EE;
}
.menusubnav a:active{
    outline:none;
    border-color:#ffa853;
    background-color:#FF6600;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #ffa853;
}
```

and here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4U3n/)

please help me how to to this. i want to focus or change color of active link of sidebar menu.
please help.

Answer (score 5):

just add a class to the active menu.

```
.active {
    outline:none;
    border-color:#ffa853;
    background-color:#FF6600;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #ffa853;
}
```

e.g.

```
<div><ul class="menusubnav">
<li class="active"><a href="Managerhomepage.php">Manager</a></li> <--look here
<li><a href="addcustomerpage.php">New Customer</a></li>
<li><a href="EditCustomer.php">Edit Customer</a></li>
<li><a href="DeleteCustomerInput.php">Delete Customer</a></li>
<li><a href="addAccount.php">New Account</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4U3n/1/

So when you load the page just add `class="active"` to the current active link of sidebar menu.

**Update:**

**Server side code**

```
<div><ul class="menusubnav">
<li <?php if($current_page == Managerhomepage.php){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?> ><a href="Managerhomepage.php">Manager</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

**Note:** not exactly how to do it but that is the concept of how to do it. I assume you would understand this since your links are redirecting to `php` pages

Comment: why what do you need?

Comment: i want to focus active menu link and that can be dynamic and you are talking about adding manualu class there in css and sidebar

Comment: it can be dynamic in server side or manual because the links are unique urls e.g. Managerhomepage.php, addcustomerpage.php, etc.

Comment: So how can i do this if you can suggest me any document link then also it can be apprecaible

Comment: Hello Sanjay, you have to add class dynamically whenever menuitem/menubar is clicked. Not adding class manually.

Comment: check update for a sample of how to add the class with server side code

Answer (score 0):

If you use Wordpress platform then it is very easy. Just add a class named `.current_page_item a` and then style it as you want. It will work for every nav menu whatever the menu item. So try it. I think it will work fine.

Comment: No wordpress only php

Answer (score -1):

Try something along these lines:

```
$('.menusubnav a').click(function() {
   $('.menusubnav a').css('background', '#ffffff');
     $(this).css('background-color', '#FF6600');
});
```

You can add your full css rules to each of the css functions.  This sets all menu items to their default condition each time one is clicked, and updates the clicked item.